# heroku can not find CSS

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have a website I am currently working on in clojure. The local version of the site works perfectly, but when I push it to heroku, it is unable to find any of my static resources. I've checked, and git is including the resources/public folder, so it should be getting uploaded to heroku.

Here is my handler code:

```
(defroutes app
           (GET "/" [] (layout/application "Home" (content/index)))
           (GET "/commission" [] (layout/application "Commission Calculator" (content/commissionForm)))
           (POST "/commission" [report] (layout/application "Commission Calculator" (content/commissionResults report)))
           (route/resources "/"))
```

The resources directory is at the same level as the src folder, and the assets are named correctly. The project is located [here](https://lit-falls-39572.herokuapp.com).

Navigating directly to https://lit-falls-39572.herokuapp.com/css/master.css, results in a 404 error, but navigating to localhost:5000/css/master.css correctly returns the css content, when I host the site locally. (Navigating to either /resources/public/css/master.css or /public/css/master.css does not work either) Does anyone have any idea why it would be behaving differently on heroku?

**Edit:** Here is the project stucture:

```
├───.idea
│   ├───copyright
│   ├───inspectionProfiles
│   └───libraries
├───dev-resources
├───lib
├───resources
│   └───public
│       ├───CSS
│       ├───images
│       │   └───home
│       └───material-design
│           ├───css
│           ├───img
│           │   ├───examples
│           │   └───flags
│           ├───js
│           └───sass
│               └───material-kit
│                   └───plugins
├───src
│   └───kandj
│       └───views
├───target
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───META-INF
│   │       └───maven
│   │           └───kandj
│   │               └───kandj
│   └───stale
└───test
```

Comment: Could you show your directory structure? (`tree .` in your project dir)

Comment: I've added the directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `CSS` directory has upper case name while your URLs use `css` lower case.

Comment: Ugh. I knew it was something dumb! I'm developing on windows, so I'm sure that's why the local version worked. Thank you!